# Hawking radiation at the mouth of Schwarzschild wormholes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, hawking-radiation, virtual-particles, wormholes

I was researching a question for another post and it occurred to me that you might expect to see Hawking radiation at the mouth of wormholes.

---

Given the mechanism of Hawking radiation at the event horizon of black holes: virtual particle pairs forming at the edge and being separated by the event horizon; would virtual particles at the edge of wormholes likewise be divided? As I understand it, the trip is one way, which should cause the spontaneous formation of electrons and separation of positrons.

---

1. Am I on the right track or is this a ridiculous assumption?
2. I don't see this in the literature on Hawking radiation or wormholes. Can you point me to any resources?
3. If this wouldn't occur, why not?

Comment: A couple of points: a) the wormhole associated with the Scharzschild metric is not traversable. I suspect you're thinking of a Morris-Thorne wormhole. The Morris-Thorne wormhole is traversable in both directions and doesn't have a horizon. b) Hawking radiation is not due to separation of particles and anti-particles, but to separation of particles with positive and negative energy. See [Black holes and positive/negative-energy particles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/black-holes-and-positive-negative-energy-particles) for more details

Comment: Good point about the Scharzchild metric. Would an Einstein-Rosen bridge be more relevant?

Comment: I think *Einstein-Rosen bridge* is synonymous with *Schwarzschild wormhole*, though i wouldn't swear to that. The [Morris-Thorne wormhole](http://relativity.livingreviews.org/open?pubNo=lrr-2004-9&amp;page=articlesu21.html) is the simplest traversible wormhole I know.

Comment: [According to Matt Visser](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0106111) Hawking radiation requires a horizon to exist. A traversible wormhole does not have any horizons therefore it will not produce Hawking radiation.