# How is it possible that pair production results in the decrease in a black holes energy?

Tags: black-holes, energy-conservation, antimatter, hawking-radiation, pair-production

I learned that pair production near black holes can cause them to loose energy, and eventually stop. But this is because quantum fluctuations cause particle and anti-particle pairs and the anti-particle gets pulled into the black hole while the other particle goes off into space. The anti-particle causes the black hole's energy to decrease. My question is why the anti-particle goes in the black hole instead of the normal particle? I read it had something to do with a red-shift, but the response was quite vague. Also if nothing was to cause the anti-particle to go in the black holes, it would be a 50-50 chance that the normal particle or anti-particle enters the black hole. This 50-50 chance would in the long run lead to no change.

I got my information after a lecture on the matter a few months ago.

Comment: Pair production is not the mechanism by which Hawking radiation is being created. That mechanism was mentioned by Hawking in his book, for whatever reason, but it's not the correct way of describing the process physically. Hawking basically came up with a "lie to kids". That is unfortunate, so is the fact that the better explanations don't seem to have a simple intuitively picture, at least I couldn't give it to you, if it exists.

Comment: CuriousOne, would you venture a chance to explain the real mechanism behind Hawking radiation then, throwing simplicity to the wind.

Comment: Also I've looked around, and all the explanations directed at Hawking radiation all revolve around pair production. So do you mean to say that Hawking radiation has nothing to do with pair production?

Comment: No, I wouldn't. :-) I tried reading a theory paper about it a while ago and it literally blew over my head. You need a theoretical physicist who actually understands the mechanism and who is willing to bypass the lies for kids.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30597/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132179/2451 and links therein.