# Hawking radiation: why do only negative mass particles fall into black holes?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

So I have read other questions asked about this topic, but they focus more on positive or negative energies of the virtual particles, and I want to ask specifically about the negative mass issue.

Please take a look at this excerpt from a BBC documentary where it is explained that, of the virtual particle pairs, only the particle with negative mass falls into the black hole: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6srN4idq1E&t=1m48s

Is it true that only the particle with negative mass falls into the black hole? If so, why?

Comment: the conserved energy in the geodesic is a root of square. This convinient propery allows some interpretations  ; not all use this concept

Comment: The explanation of Hawking radiation by "one fo the virtual particles falling into the black hole" is not the actual description in the theory (there it is just the application of the Unruh effect to the black hole, no virtual particles needed) - The premise of your question is false, there are no "negative mass particles falling into black holes".

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Black holes and positive/negative-energy particles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/black-holes-and-positive-negative-energy-particles)

Comment: "The premise of your question is false, there are no "negative mass particles falling into black holes""

So what is described in that BBC documentary is false?

Comment: @AllochthonousKlippe Yes, it is false. It is an explanation used in some popular shows, but it is not how it is explained by the actual theory. I am not sure why someone invented such misleading explanation. It often happens that popular explanations are simplified for the public, because the theory is difficult, but this one went too far.

Comment: @AllochthonousKlippe : one must edit wikipedia [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Overview) , 3rd paragraph of the overview.

Comment: @AllochthonousKlippe : another reference for negative energy ( direct pdf ) [Physics 161: Black Holes Kim Griest Department of Physics, University of California, San Diego, CA 92093 / course year 2014](https://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/spring2014/physics161/book.pdf) page 87