# Why isn't Hawking radiation of negative energy?

Tags: black-holes, hawking-radiation

Hawking radiation is explained by particle-antiparticle creation. A particle with positive energy escapes away from the black hole while the particle with negative energy falls down.

Why isn't that vice versa? A particle with positive mass should fall down due to gravity force, while the negative mass is to be repeled by the gravity force?

Edit:
I think was wrong about the gravity repeling the negative mass. Even though the force is directed away from the black hole, a=F/m so the particle still falls down the black hole!
Now I see no point why any particles should be escaping more than the other?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter Seems like the current understanding is that antiparticles have positive mass still (though I know very little about this, so I can't really give an answer or any useful information besides what I found on google).

Comment: Is the negative energy same as negative mass? mass is invariant property of (fundamental) particles and there is no known particle with negative mass...

Comment: @Umaxo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/black-holes-and-positive-negative-energy-particles Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251385/an-explanation-of-hawking-radiation

Comment: @0xF i do not think the article applies, since it is highly spekulative and existence of hawking radiation should not depend on wheter such mass exists or not.

Comment: Have a look at [this video about Hawking Radiation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPKj0YnKANw)