# Why black holes lose energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, energy-conservation, event-horizon, hawking-radiation

It is often said that black holes lose energy throughout the process called Hawking radiation. My question is, since the process of creating particles is random, why do the black holes captures more particles with negative energy than particles with positive energy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black holes and positive/negative-energy particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30597/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) notes, when one particle escapes the event horizon but a partner particle doesn't, the latter isn't the issue (as its energy neither enters nor leaves), but the former has more energy due to a [gravitational redshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift). This amplification produces a partner wave. It's this wave that actually returns negative energy to the black hole.