# Vacuum fluctuation and negative energy

Tags: energy, black-holes, antimatter, hawking-radiation

I was reading this post [Black holes and positive/negative-energy particles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30597/black-holes-and-positive-negative-energy-particles) because I was wondering how Hawking radiation works and why always the anti-particle falls into a black hole, which is nicely explained there.

However, I feel that I have an understanding problem what vacuum fluctuation really is. Is it a pair of particle-anti-particle, e.g. electron and positron (as I assumed...) or positive-negative-mass-particle? If the latter is true, what is the negative particle then, surely not a positron...?

Matter/antimatter or matter/negative-matter is not the same and it's important when understanding Hawking radiation (as in the post mentioned above). That is because anti-particles like positrons have still positive mass, thus falling into the black hole would just grow the hole. (Or in other words: If we would produce antimatter in particle accelerators and pour it into a black hole, it would grow, correct?)

Also, if vacuum fluctuations consist of positive and negative mass (or energy), the annihilation would produce zero energy, whereas I thought the explanation for vacuum fluctuations is some remaining "zero-point-energy" in quantum mechanics... thus I assumed real antimatter.

Comment: What is negative matter? The particle that falls into the black hole has negative energy - it falls into the black hole thereby decreasing the total energy/mass of the black hole. The particle that leaves the black hole has positive energy.

Comment: @Prahar Mitra, Well, that's exactly my question: Is there a difference between antimatter and matter of negative energy? I think yes, because the annihilation of a particle with its anti-particle (as produced in accelerators) produces a lot of energy, which is not possible if the anti-particle would have negative energy.

Comment: The particle that enters the black hole must have negative energy, but it could be a matter particle or an anti-matter particle. There is no correlation between the two. Annihilation of two matter and anti-matter particles with both positive energy produces a lot of energy, but if one of them has negative energy, then they don't.

Comment: Note that its crucial that we're in a BH background and in a region near the horizon of a black hole. In flat spacetime, particles cannot have negative energy so the annihilation process always produces large amounts of energy. However, there is a region outside the horizon of a black hole known as the ergosphere where particles may have negative energy. Negative energy particles are forever confined within the ergosphere and eventually fall into the black hole whereas positive energy particles can escape the ergosphere to a far away observer where it would be observed as Hawking Radiation.

Comment: @Prahar Mitra, that's interesting! So the negative energy is not associated with a negative mass (because of E=m*c^2)?

Comment: $E^2=m^2c^4 + p^2 c^2$ holds in SR (in flat spacetime). In GR, energy is a very tricky concept. In many cases, energy is not even a quantity that exists. Even when it exists as a conserved quantity, it is a tricky concept and one has to be very careful about who is measuring the energy. For instance, when I said that energy is -ve - I meant that it is -ve as measured by a far away observer (in an inertial frame). Observers falling into the black hole will measure positive energy.

Comment: Also, negative mass doesn't exist. Nothing ever has negative mass - EVER. Not in SR, not in QFT, not in GR.

Comment: @safesphere So when arbitrarily defining the potential energy to zero at infinity, then both partners have negative energy when created, but the one partner who escapes to infinity has in the end a potential energy of zero, while the other's potential energy even decreases when falling into the hole?

Comment: @safesphere: what means the black spends it energy to produce a particle-antiparticle pair? I thought that's a stochastical effect happening everywhere always...?

Comment: @safesphere: Then this separation is the work (energy) that the black hole spends and looses, right? I was all the years just misleaded by people saying an antiparticle of negative energy falls into the hole, thinking that there are some special properties like negative energy or mass of the falling particle responsible for the black hole to shrink...

Comment: @safesphere: Cool! But what if a starship approaches a black hole and gets ripped by tidal forces so that one half of the ship is blown into free space while the other half falls into the hole? The hole wouldn't shrink then. Can this be explained by potential energy as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I feel that I have an understanding problem what vacuum fluctuation really is.

It is hypothetical loops or particle-antiparticle pairs. Hypothetical because if there is no real particle with a fourvector from which the loop can get some energy, there is no way to detect it. Loops of particle-antiparticle are in higher order Feynman diagrams and are used to get [better calculations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222511596_Extrapolation_of_the_Za-expansion_and_two-loop_bound-state_energy_shifts/figures?lo=1) for observables as crossections and decays.

[image: vacuum loops]

> However, I feel that I have an understanding problem what vacuum fluctuation really is. Is it a pair of particle-anti-particle, e.g. electron and positron (as I assumed...) or positive-negative-mass-particle? If the latter is true, what is the negative particle then, surely not a positron...?

The invariant mass of [elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) that can be in particle antiparticle pairs is always larger than zero, neutrinos, electron-positron, quark-antiquark....

> That is because anti-particles like positrons have still positive mass, thus falling into the black hole would just grow the hole

Not true. The hypothetical loop pair of electron-positron takes its [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) (energy/momentum) from the fields of the horizon. When the electron is absorbed because its momentum was pointing down to the black hole, the positron escapes with its part of the energy/momentum,  (vice verso for positron electron)and thus the black hole loses mass, not gains.

> If we would produce antimatter in particle accelerators and pour it into a black hole, it would grow, correct?)

That antimatter  would not have any connection with the black hole, and by falling in would increase the mass of the black hole. Hawking radiation takes energy/momentum out of the black hole, that is why [micro black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_black_hole) from the Big Bang are supposed to have evaporated by now.

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive answer! But I always thougt mass and energy are the same according to E=m*c^2. So when the anti-particle has negative energy... then it must have a negative mass as well?

Comment: The m in the formula is misleading. It is not the invariant mass but the inertial mass of a particle  moving at relativistic energies. the invariant and this m coincide only when the particles are at rest . The negative in energy comes from balancing energy content, it is a component of a fourvector, not an invariant..  see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: to conclude, vacuum fluctuations produce particle-antiparticle pairs, e.g. electron-positron, both having positive mass (in our everyday meaning of what is mass, and there is no negative mass anyways). But one of it, when falling into a black hole, behaves like having negative energy, no matter if that's the electron or positron. Is that correct?

Comment: not negative energy per se. One has to do the subtraction from the combined four momentum vector of the pair, the  four momentum vector of the one escaping in order to know the four momentum of the absorbed.

Comment: @safesphere yes, the loop part has taken over in illustrations  the mostly photon part. It is a similar mechanicsm as black body radiation , a  charged particle falls into the horizon becoming part of the black hole, but there is a probability of interacting with other charges and fields  and some of those interactions have a probability to have  a photon in a direction that allows  it to  escape the inevitable attraction of the black hole, the four vector of the escaped  photon diminishing the mass of the black hole.